# Bitbucket Push Request Response

Tags: bitbucket

I have pushed my code changes to bitbucket today and I am getting the following message in rainbow colours from the command line:

remote: 
remote: ++++                               ++++
remote:   +++++++                     +++++++  
remote:      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     
remote:          +++++++++++++++++++++         
remote:                 +++++++                
remote:       +++                     +++      
remote:       ++++++     +++++     ++++++      
remote:        ++++++    +++++    ++++++       
remote:        +++++++    +++    +++++++       
remote:         ++++++++   +   ++++++++        
remote:          ++++++++     ++++++++         
remote:            ++++++++ +++++++++          
remote:             +++++++++++++++             
remote:              +++++++++++++              
remote:                +++++++++                
remote:                  +++++++                
remote:               +   +++++++               
remote:              +++   +++++++              
remote:             ++++++  +++++++             
remote:            +++++++   +++++++            
remote:           +++++++     +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
remote:          +++++++       +++++++           
remote:

What is it supposed to represent?  Is it to do with it being the summer solstice in the northern hemisphere?  Is it a person with the sun overhead?

Comment: It's the Atlassian logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- When you push to a Git server, it can send arbitrary text back that is displayed on your terminal. This is frequently used for error messages, information on the server you are pushing to, or the like.

#### In this case, it is the Atlassian Logo, as Atlassian are the owners of Bitbucket, colored using ANSI escape sequences as a rainbow, likely to celebrate today's World Yoga Day.

[image: Atlasian logo]

Many sites around the internet have switched to rainbow colored version of their logo for similar reasons, including StackOverflow. Of course, as a US decision, this is probably going to be puzzling to some of those outside of the US.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with World Yoga day, and more to do with June being Pride month and the month most US cities have pride parades.